# Multi threading application error C++

Tags: c++, multithreading

I am trying to alter a multi threaded scheduling application. I run into an error with the following line of code.

```
VirtualGridDriver::AddTask(& CSchedulerDlg::runJob, parameters)
```

The error message is:

```
error C2664: 'VirtualGridDriver::AddTask' : cannot convert parameter 1 from 'void (__thiscall CSchedulerDlg::* )(VGridTaskParam)' to 'void (__cdecl *)(VGridTaskParam)'
1>        There is no context in which this conversion is possible
```

The function `AddTask` is defined as:

```
CString VirtualGridDriver::AddTask(void (*proc)(VGridTaskParam parameters), VGridTaskParam parameters ) { //add implementation here}
```

How do I fix this?

Comment: The context is too narrow to tell concisely. I'd suspect difference between member function definition and `static` member function definition, but cannot tell finally with the information you provide.

Comment: Is `runJob` a static function? Also, what version of C++?

Comment: @DavidSchwartz, clearly, runJob **is not** - obvious from the error message.

Comment: @SergeyA Then the code in the question makes no sense at all. (Which I guess is possible.)

Comment: @DavidSchwartz, I guess, OP is not the first one to try to use non-static member as a callback function. Not the last either.

Comment: Was looking for a good duplicate on member functions as callback - found one from 2008, but nothing more recent. Do we have one?

Comment: @James We need to know whether `runJob` is a static function or not. And if not, could you explain how you're expecting this to work? (You need an instance of the class to call a non-static member function on, right? Where are you expecting that instance to come from?)

Comment: In the original code, runJob() was static, but I had to alter it and make it non-static

Comment: @James Can you update your question to explain *why* you had to do that? Because as it stands, your question doesn't make much sense. Presumably you needed to do that to access some members of a particular class instance. But there is *no* class instance in the code you gave us. So we can't see how you could even have expected it to possibly work.

Answer (score 2):

You can't pass non-static member function pointers as free function pointers.  Totally different types, as the compiler is telling you.

Comment: I had to make some members static. Is there some way to fix this error?

Comment: @James Create a free function that calls `CSchedulerDlg::runJob`.

Comment: As correct as the answer is, I doubt it's going to help OP, it doesn't answer the question.

Comment: If you think this doesn't answer the question you are free to provide your own answer.  vOv